# Looking for a murder mystery with a woman and her male clone

Tags: story-identification, clones

Here is what I remember:

1. Read in the late 80's or early 90's.
2. Main character is a woman, but as a child, had been gender swapped to male.
3. Recently "woke up" as a previous incarnation had been brutally murdered.
4. Turns out that there is a male version of herself, an illegal clone.
5. Takes place on a space station, so the extra clone is using valuable resources.
6. The clone was created by mistake. Some criminals stole several clones and revived them, believing one of them would be worth ransoming.

Comment: Did they have an artistic hobby of sculpting weather events?

Comment: Not that I can remember.  I've added more to the list.

Comment: I assume that this book was set in he future

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I read this one as part of a collection, but I can't seem to find it in my recent reading history. I remember another one of the stories in the collection involved a pair of "half siblings" on another planet in the solar system (Mercury or Venus, I think) who have to come to grips with that one of them is a clone of the other, culminating in a scene where they're stuck in a cave-in on a lake of mercury, skin-to-skin as the result of a need to share their energy-field spacesuits.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I think that's a different collection, but these are both John Varley stories set in his Ophiuchi Hotline history.

Comment: While this may turn out to be a duplicate, we don't close story-id questions as dupes unless the OP confirms that the dupe contains the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the stories included in one of John Varley's *Ophiuchi Hotline* collections -- I believe it's *The Barbie Murders*, the individual story is titled ["The Phantom of Kansas"](https://varley.net/excerpt/the-phantom-of-kansas-full-text/) (thanks, FuzzyBoots!).  Fox, a weather designer, is the victim of a botched attempt at clone-napping.  The conflict arises because of Lunar law, which prohibits two living people having the same genome (Varley never did say what they'd do with natural identical twins -- reproduction was assisted enough by then, they might never had had those).  The clone, who calls himself Rat, makes himself known to Fox by real-time tampering with a tornado Fox had designed.

In the end, they find a way to get Rat onto a ship bound for Pluto, where genetic laws like Luna's don't (yet) exist, so Rat won't be under a death sentence.

Comment: That's the one I was thinking of. Thank you.

Comment: It's "The Phantom of Kansas" (https://varley.net/excerpt/the-phantom-of-kansas-full-text/)

Comment: FWIW, I read it in the *Persistence of Vision" anthology, which has the bit with the mercury lake.